# Training The Ubuntu Dialog Corpus with chatterbot

Tags: python, chatterbot

How much time does it take to train the Ubuntu Dialog Corpus with chatterbot? How many examples are needed to train the bot well?

Answer (score 1):

Current chatterbot train based on your input file size, if the train file is bigger it will take more time to train the bot.

There is no specific examples to train the bot, it will learn past user inputs and responds your answers

Comment: Can you show any example / tutorial that how to do Corpus training from my existing data? @Mallikarjunarao Kosuri